# I got the following error when trying to add a dependency using poetry. How do i resolve it?

Tags: addition, artifactory, python-poetry

I have poetry installed and I am trying to add packages.

I have my toml file set as follows:

```
name = "your-project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Your project description"
authors = ["Your Name <your.email@example.com>"]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"

[tool.poetry.dependencies.package-name]
version = "1.2.3"
# Add your other dependencies here

[tool.poetry.repositories]
artifactory = 
url = "https:org-artifactory" 
}
```

However, I am getting an error that says

HTTPSConnectionPoo] (host= artifactrepository.org.net ', port-443): Max retries exceeded with url: org-artifactory (Caused by SSLError (SSLCertVerificationError (1, [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)))

Please help!!